Problem with installing Angular Materials
I'm working on a project with Angular 17 and I've decided to use Angular Materials, the problem is, I cannot install it. Here's what the terminal says:
The package @angular/material@17.3.10 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ngrx/store@18.0.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@17.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.3" from @angular/animations@17.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"17.3.3" from @angular/platform-browser@17.3.3     
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"17.3.3" from @angular/forms@17.3.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!         2 more (the root project, @angular/material)
npm ERR!       5 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, ...)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"17.3.3" from @angular/platform-server@17.3.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!       peerOptional @angular/platform-server@"^17.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.3.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     2 more (the root project, @angular/material)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.3" from @angular/common@17.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"17.3.3" from @angular/forms@17.3.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!         @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (the root project, @angular/material)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"17.3.3" from @angular/platform-browser@17.3.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"17.3.3" from @angular/forms@17.3.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!         2 more (the root project, @angular/material)
npm ERR!       5 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, ...)
npm ERR!     13 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, ...)
npm ERR!   17 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^18.0.0" from @ngrx/store@18.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngrx/store
npm ERR!   @ngrx/store@"^18.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@18.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^18.0.0" from @ngrx/store@18.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ngrx/store
npm ERR!     @ngrx/store@"^18.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\germa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-04T18_44_13_289Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\germa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-04T18_44_13_289Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.

I still do not know how to work with npm conflicts
I tried to see what can be causing the conflict. I have installed bootstrap, ngbootstrap, and others like ngxtranslate and rxjs. I tried to use --force but nothing.

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@18.2.3
This line above shows that it looks like you have the angular 18 core packages, which are incompatible with material 17. Have you tried downgrading the other angular packages to 17 if you are truly on 17, or installing material 18 if you are actually on 18?

Upgrade to angular 18 or downgrade @ngrx/store to 17.X.X
Your library @ngrx/store@18.0.2 is compatible with angular 18, not angular 17. It must have been force installed. You should start by fixing that issue
